# Laravel Echo 500 error (broadcasting/auth)?

Tags: php, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, pusher, laravel-echo

have a nice day !

I have a problem:
I set up Laravel Echo & Pusher but got this error, have no idea to resolve :(

[image]

I checked my app-key, app-cluster but all are correct.

Can someone help me?

**app.js**

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        messages: []
    },
    methods:{
        addMessage(message){
            this.messages.push(message);
            axios.post('/messages', message).then(response => {
               console.log(response);
            });
        }
    },
    created(){
        axios.get('/messages').then(response => {
            this.messages = response.data;
        });

        Echo.channel('chatroom')
            .listen('MessageEvent', (e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }
})
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '************',
    cluster: 'ap1',
    encrypted: false
});
```

**MessageEvent**

```
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
public $message, $user;

public function __construct(Message $message, User $user)
{
    $this->message = $message;
    //query
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PresenceChannel('chatroom');
}
```

**channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('chatroom', function ($user, $id) {
    return $user;
});
```

Comment: Does your `laravel.log` file contain anything?

Answer (score 6):

Error 403 or 500 /broadcasting/auth with Laravel version > 5.3 & Pusher, you need change your code in **resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js** with

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your key',
    cluster: 'your cluster',
    encrypted: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + YourTokenLogin
        },
    },
});
```

And in **app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php** change by

```
Broadcast::routes()
```

with

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
```

or

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']]); //if you use JWT
```

it worked for me, and hope it help you.

Comment: This is the right answer!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the $id as you are not passing from the event

```
Broadcast::channel('chatroom', function ($user) {
  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give an authentic point if u have used laravel echo just goto
Resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

Just add the following line inside the window

```
Echo = new Echo({
authEndpoint : 'http://localhost/projectName/public/broadcasting/auth',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're working on localhost make sure that your .env file is set up properly

try setting

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
DB_HOST=localhost
```

and run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

hope this will help you.